# How to give a value to a checkbox if it is not selected - php

Tags: php

In my form I have two checkboxes

-role
-commercial

I implemented an if loop that sees that the checkbox called role must be used

the second "commercial" checkbox is optional but how can I pass the "N" value when it is not selected?

Because in the current state in the db the commercial field, if its checkbox is not selected and I send the form, it gives me a null result

code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['RUOLO'] == 'N' )
    {
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
            {
                include 'FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE.php';

                $id = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
                $role = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['role']);
                $commerciali = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['commerciali']);

                $query = mysqli_query($VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE, "UPDATE tabella SET role='$role', commerciali='$commerciali'  WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['USER_ID']);

                if( $query )
                {
                    if(isset($_POST['role'])) 
                    {
                         $role = ($_POST['role']);
                         echo "ok";
                    } 

                    else 
                    {
                        echo "errore";
                    }
                }


            }
    } 

} 
?>


<form method="post" action="n.php">
<input class="form-control"  name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['USER_ID'];  ?>"><br>

<label>Privacy</label>
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" value="S" required   name="role" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['RUOLO']; ?>"><br>

<label>Termini e Condizioni</label>
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" value="S"  name="commerciali" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['RUOLO']; ?>"><br>



<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Register..."><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: You could also combine the three first `if`-statements into one single statement.

Comment: `$commercial = isset($_POST['commercial']) ? $_POST['commercial'] : 'N';` something like that?

Comment: If a checkbox isn't checked, then it won't be posted at all so they can't send you any value. You need to set the default value using PHP if it doesn't exist, like @Qirel suggests.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST) {

if(isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'] && $_SESSION['RUOLO'] == 'N') { 

    include 'FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE.php';

    $id = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $role = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['role']);

    if(!isset($_POST['commerciali'])) {
        $commerciali = "N";
    } else {
    $commerciali = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['commerciali']);
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `tabella` SET `role`='$role', `commerciali`='$commerciali'  WHERE `id` = $id";

    $result = mysqli_query($VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE, $query);

    if($result && isset($_POST['role'])) {
             $role = ($_POST['role']);
             echo "ok";
    } else {
            echo "error";
    }
```

}

the `if(array_key_exists('submit',$_POST) {` helps check that unless the form's submit button is clicked and sent with the form's post array.. nothing should run.. personally find more secure cause of bots that are capable of submitting forms with their own data.. also takes care of the if statement for submit check.

And answering your question is the `if(!isset($_POST['commerciali'])) {`part. 
I hope this helps!